# how to change ruby version in Pry

Tags: ruby, rvm, pry

My command line ruby is 1.9.2 thanks to RVM, yet when I launch pry (which point to a 1.9.2 gem) it uses ruby 1.8.7

Do you know where is the ruby version pry uses specified ?

```
macflashy:~ $rvm info
ruby:
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "1.9.2p290"
  date:         "2011-07-09"
  platform:     "x86_64-darwin11.1.0"
  patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
  full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]"

homes:
  gem:          "/Users/nrolland/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
  ruby:         "/Users/nrolland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

macflashy:~ $ruby -v
   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]

macflashy:~ $ which pry
   /Users/nrolland/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/pry

macflashy:~ $ pry
  [1] pry(main)> RUBY_VERSION
  => "1.8.7"
```

Comment: if i do from the command line ruby -e 'require pry; binding.pry' then the ruby version is indeed 1.9.2

Comment: @nicholas i would say there's something screwey with your environment; try uninstalling pry from your system ruby.

Comment: indeed. uninstall/reinstall worked..... strange

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall of pry did not work for me.

When I type `pry -v` I get `Pry version 0.12.2 on Ruby 2.3.0` whereas `ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.6.0rc2 (2018-12-15 trunk 66408) [x86_64-linux]` and `rbenv global` and `rbenv local` both give `2.6.0-rc2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this is possible. Can you do a gist to show that you're using ruby version 1.9 on RVM and yet pry is running 1.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It looks like you have several versions of ruby on your system. If you don't have the gem `pry` installed for your current version of ruby, it will fallback to a previously installed version of pry. To do this, it has to run it from a previous version of ruby as well. Like Henry said, try to uninstall pry then reinstall it. In my case, it was never installed for the newer version of ruby. After I installed it, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall pry:

```
sudo gem uninstall pry

sudo gem install pry
```