# Pry running with obsolete Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rbenv, pry

When I type `pry -v` I get

> Pry version 0.12.2 on Ruby 2.3.0

whereas `ruby -v` gives

> ruby 2.6.0rc2 (2018-12-15 trunk 66408) [x86_64-linux]

and `rbenv global` and `rbenv local` both give

> 2.6.0-rc2.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pry as suggested in an answer to [how to change ruby version in Pry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8026059/948073).

Comment: If your system supports it, `which pry` for one will tell you where `pry` is coming from. You may want to `gem install pry`.

Comment: `which pry` points to a bash script at `~/.rbenv/shims/pry`. Pry should be taking its cues from rbenv.

Comment: That should be it, so `rbenv` seems to be letting you down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `pry` installed as a global executable, from the system ruby. This won't be overridden by any ruby installed by `rbenv`, unless the `pry` gem is installed *in that specific ruby version*.

It's just a matter of the system searching $PATH for an executable file called `pry`.

Most probably, if you `gem install pry` under rbenv, then the new pry will use the correct ruby binary.

**EDIT**:

Whops, @tadman's comment has exactly the same content. If it is converted to an answer I will delete mine.

Comment: Interesting. `gem install pry` worked this time. Can't think of anything I did differently from last time, except for not uninstalling before reinstalling.

Comment: This is a much longer explanation than mine, so it's all good.